# RPC over an existing connection with Golang

Tags: go, rpc

I have an existing TCP connection (`net.Conn`) on which I am trying to use (develop) an RPC client-server application.

So far, I explored gRPC and net/rpc in the standard lib; unless I am missing something, both seem to need full control over the connection(s).

I could just go for a custom implementation with gob to serialize requests/replies but since I also require a decent error handling (at least for errors I am generating on the server side) I am trying to see if there is some existing framework I could use.

Any pointers/ideas?

Comment: [fast http](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp) also uses the same http2 protocl

Comment: There is a popular library cmux available in go for connection multiplexing that might be usefull link: https://github.com/soheilhy/cmux

Comment: Thanks Chetan, this is useful. This could be an answer as it allows exactly what I was after, with more flexibility wrt the solution I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I realized I was wrong about net/rpc. Apologies for that.

You can call `rpc.ServeConn` on server side and `rpc.NewClient` on client-side passing an existing connection, as long as it implements `io.ReadWriteCloser`

Example server:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/rpc"
    "os"

    "myapp/pkg"
)

func main() {
    fsops := new(pkg.FSOps)
    s := rpc.NewServer()
    s.Register(fsops)
    s.ServeConn(pkg.RWCloser{os.Stdin, os.Stdout})
}
```

Example client:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/rpc"
    "os"

    "myapp/pkg"
)

func main() {
    client := rpc.NewClient(pkg.RWCloser{os.Stdin, os.Stdout})

    var reply pkg.XXXReply
    err := client.Call("FSOps.XXX", "args", &reply)

}
```